# Как зайти в Bash скрипте в Screen и выполнить команду backup

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, gnu-screen

1. Мне нужно с помощью crontab заходить в screen с сервером и вводить внутри команду /backup. Не могу понять, как выполнить ее внутри скрина.
2. Потом в скрипте нужно (вероятно) выйти из screen. Я не очень понимаю как crontab работает с сессиями, неужели она выйдет как-то автоматом.

Comment: зачем заходить в скрин?

Comment: В куче инфы по нему в инете, не было ни слова о "-X".

Answer (score 0):

```
screen -X stuff '/backup\n'
```

И выходить, по идее не надо.